# Facing issue while sending special character in blackberry Text Message?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I am using below code to send text message:

```
DatagramConnection dc = null;
    try 
    {
    dc = (DatagramConnection) Connector.open("sms://" + monum);
    byte[] data = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
    Datagram dg = dc.newDatagram(dc.getMaximumLength());
    dg.setData(data, 0, data.length);
    dc.send(dg);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
```

Text I am sending is support@gizmocontrol.com but on Device i m receiving 'i' in place of '@'. How can i receive '@' in text message?

Comment: Did u try sending the same txt MSG to another device other than a blackberry? Try to see if the problem is with blackberry or the way the MSG is sent.

Comment: Yes i have done, i used Nokia and Android phone.

Comment: in all cases it shows same

Comment: I'm surprised as there is nothing special about the @ character. It is a normal ASCII. I am not aware of class Datagram. May I know what API is this?

Comment: I think its with blackberry eclipse, because same is working fine with android eclipse

Comment: To debug, what you can do is print out the data[] array contents and see if there are any difference between blackberry and android sdk.

Comment: Its Giving same only in case of text messages where as in email it gives '@' as it is.

Comment: Can you confirm for the same text like abc@yahoo.com, it converts into identical byte array in both blackberry and android? If they are identical byte array, then the problem may be on the receiving device on how it decodes the bytes back into characters.